# Change default action route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to change the route of my action method:

```
[Route("NewEvalution")]
// GET: BackOffice/EvaluationHeaders/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.EntityId = new SelectList(context.CompanyEntity, "EntityId", "EntityName");
    return View();
}
```

I want the route to look like this:

> BackOffice/EvaluationHeaders/NewEvalution

Comment: Update 

> [Route("NewEvalution")]

to 

> [Route("~/BackOffice/EvaluationHeaders/NewEvalution")]

Comment: Does your controller class have a RoutePrefix attribute? Show us the controller class.

Comment: no i dont have  RoutePrefix attribute but my controller in Areas **BackOffice**

Answer (score 0):

Just set the route in the Route attribute:

```
[Route("BackOffice/EvaluationHeaders/NewEvalution")]
```